# React Data-Table search component not rendering/working like it should

Tags: reactjs, npm, search, datatable

I am using an npm package called react-datatable for a project and I am trying to build out a way to search through the data. I found a repo where someone was able to do this; however, his react skills are above mine and I cannot seem to make his code work properly on my end. I would just like to know why it isn't rendering anything on my front end. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

His code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import faker from 'faker';
import Button from '../shared/Button';
import DataTable from '../../../src/index';

const createUser = () => ({
  id: faker.random.uuid(),
  name: faker.name.findName(),
  email: faker.internet.email(),
  address: faker.address.streetAddress(),
  bio: faker.lorem.sentence(),
  image: faker.image.avatar(),
});

const createUsers = (numUsers = 5) =>
  new Array(numUsers).fill(undefined).map(createUser);

const fakeUsers = createUsers(2000);

const TextField = styled.input`
  height: 32px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 0 32px 0 16px;

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

const ClearButton = styled(Button)`
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;


const FilterComponent = ({ filterText, onFilter, onClear }) => (
  <>
    <TextField id="search" type="text" placeholder="Filter By Name" aria-label="Search Input" value={filterText} onChange={onFilter} />
    <ClearButton type="button" onClick={onClear}>X</ClearButton>
  </>
);

const columns = [
  {
    name: 'Name',
    selector: 'name',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Email',
    selector: 'email',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Address',
    selector: 'address',
    sortable: true,
  },
];

const BasicTable = () => {
  const [filterText, setFilterText] = React.useState('');
  const [resetPaginationToggle, setResetPaginationToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const filteredItems = fakeUsers.filter(item => item.name && item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase()));

  const subHeaderComponentMemo = React.useMemo(() => {
    const handleClear = () => {
      if (filterText) {
        setResetPaginationToggle(!resetPaginationToggle);
        setFilterText('');
      }
    };

    return <FilterComponent onFilter={e => setFilterText(e.target.value)} onClear={handleClear} filterText={filterText} />;
  }, [filterText, resetPaginationToggle]);

  return (
    <DataTable
      title="Contact List"
      columns={columns}
      data={filteredItems}
      pagination
      paginationResetDefaultPage={resetPaginationToggle} // optionally, a hook to reset pagination to page 1
      subHeader
      subHeaderComponent={subHeaderComponentMemo}
      selectableRows
      persistTableHead
    />
  );
};

storiesOf('Filtering', module)
  .add('Example 1', () => <BasicTable />)
```

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import NotesListHtml from './NoteListHtml'
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';


const FilterComponent = ( { filterText, onClear, onFilter }) => (
  <>
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Filter By Name" aria-label="Search Input" value={filterText} onChange={onFilter} />
    <button type="button" onClick={onClear}>X</button>
  </>
)

const BasicTable = (props) => {
  let result = props.notes.map(function(el) {
    var o = Object.assign({}, el);
    o.fullName = `${props.data.first_name} ${props.data.last_name}`;
    return o;
  })
  

const ExpandableComponent = ({ data }) =>{
 return(<p style={{padding:'20px'}}>{data.contentBody}</p>)
}  
  const columns = [
    {
      name: 'Organization',
      selector: row => row.type[0].label || row.type,
      sortable: true,
      wrap:true
    },
    {
      name: 'Title',
      selector: 'title',
      sortable: true,
    },
      {
        name: 'Date',
        selector: row=>row.createdAt.split('T')[0],
        sortable: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'Author',
        selector: 'fullName',
        sortable: true,
      },
  ];

  const customStyles = {
    headCells: {
      style: {
          backgroundColor:'#f3f7f9',
      },
    },
    cells: {
      style: {
      color:'#79838b'
      },
    },
  };



  const [filterText, setFilterText] = React.useState('');
  const [resetPaginationToggle, setResetPaginationToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const filteredItems = props.notes.filter(item => item.type[0].label && item.type[0].label.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase()))


  const subHeaderComponentMemo = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.log('subheader')
    const handleClear = () => {
      console.log('hit1')
      if (filterText) {
        setResetPaginationToggle(!resetPaginationToggle);
        setFilterText('');
      }
    }
    console.log('beforereturn');
    return (
    <>
    {/* <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Filter By Name" aria-label="Search Input" value={filterText} onChange={onFilter} /> */}
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClear}>X</button>
    </>
    )

  }, [filterText, resetPaginationToggle])



  return (
    <>
    <DataTable
      subHeaderComponent={subHeaderComponentMemo}
      className='table'
      columns={columns}
      data={filteredItems}
      pagination={true}
      highlightOnHover={true}
      pointerOnHover={true}
      expandableRows={true}
      expandOnRowClicked={true}
      expandableRowsComponent={<ExpandableComponent data={result} />}
      paginationResetDefaultPage={resetPaginationToggle} // optionally, a hook to reset pagination to page 1
      customStyles={customStyles}
      subHeader={false}

    />
    </>

  );
}

export default BasicTable;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with 'why it isn't rendering anything on my front end'. Can you also include how your data looks? Maybe put it in a sandbox?